# Вставка в упорядоченный массив. JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

Задан массив, упорядоченный по росту. Нужно вставить в массив новый элемент так, чтобы порядок не нарушился. Сделать через функцию, которая изменяет исходный массив и не создает новый массив. Помогите пожалуйста, новичок в JS, прошу объяснять попроще.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function insert(a, x) {
  // Предполагаю, что в массиве по ключу -1 не лежит какое-то число

  for (var q=a.length-1; a[q] > x; --q) {
    a[q+1] = a[q]
  }
  
  a[q+1] = x
  return a
}


console.log(insert([1, 5, 6, 8, 10, 100], 0).join(", "))
console.log(insert([1, 5, 6, 8, 10, 100], 7).join(", "))
console.log(insert([1, 5, 6, 8, 10, 100], 700).join(", "))
console.log(insert([], 42).join(", "))
console.log(insert([7], 10).join(", "))
console.log(insert([7], 4).join(", "))
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140259/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy-----js).